# Do delegate methods inherit from method in protocol class?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

In a category I got from a book, there is a protocol specified.  It requires one method and declares that method in the category as well.

If I implement the protocol in another object (a table view cell), my understanding is that I MUST include the required method.  However, other than the title of the method being the same as the one in the category, do I inherit any of the code from the category version?  That code is meaningful because only after that code completes do I want to do something.

category: .m

```
@protocol DownloadHelperDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didCompleteDownloadForURL:(NSString *)url withData:(NSMutableData *)data;

@end

- (void)didCompleteDownloadForURL:(NSString *)url withData:(NSMutableData *)data{
    // doThis
    // doThat
    // readyToDoSomethingElsewhere
}
```

In tableviewCell: .h

```
#import "category.h";
@protocol category
```

.m

```
-(void)didCompleteDownloadForURL:url withData:data;
{
    // Did doThis happen?
    // Did doThat happen?
    // If so, I want to do Something 
}
```

Comment: What class is the category a category on? Show its `@interface` line. Also, what is the superclass (a.k.a. base class) of the class you're implementing? Might as well show your class's `@interface` line, too. Finally, protocols and categories are two completely different things, but you seem to be conflating them (e.g. `@protocol category`). You may need to show more to clarify.

Comment: The category is a category on UIImageView.  It's interface line is@interface UIImageView (RemoteFile).  The class implementing is a custom tableview cell...@interface IDTVCell : UITableViewCell<DownloadHelperDelegate>.  This protocol happens to be burred in a category...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the category is a category on `UIImageView`, it only adds methods to that class.

Since your class is derived from `UITableViewCell` and that does not derive, directly or indirectly, from `UIImageView`, it does not inherit an implementation of `-didCompleteDownloadForURL:withData:` from the category.

I'm guessing the category's method would not be an appropriate implementation of the protocol method, anyway. It has the same signature, but I suspect it has a different purpose. In particular, I suspect the category method's purpose is, at least in part, to forward the call along to a delegate which implements the protocol. So, it wouldn't make sense for the delegate itself to inherit that implementation.

It's just a coincidence that the category method and the protocol method have the same signature. In fact, I would suggest that the category method be changed to start with a unique prefix so that there's no chance that it collides with a method on `UIImageView`, which might be private to Apple or added in a future version of UIKit.

Comment: OK.  Can you suggest a way for the tableviewcell to learn that the download carried out in the UIImageView category is complete?

Comment: Presumably, the category adds a new delegate property or some method takes a delegate parameter. You would pass the cell as that delegate. I assume it defined the protocol for a reason. Where is that protocol referenced in the category's API?